# One column to multiple columns in SQL Server based on ID

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table structure :

ID   |Type              |Value
1     Email                  abcd@xyz.com
1     Phone                 12345 
2     Phone                  56789  
2     WorkPhone        546789

I want to transform it into

ID   |Email                           |Phone      |WorkPhone
1     abcd@xyz.com         12345        Null 
2     Null                                  56789        546789

Can anyone please help me to solve it. Sorry if this question has been repeated before.

Comment: search for `pivot`

Comment: Thanks. Will check it.

Comment: Tagging mysql and mssql doesn't work...choose one or the other for your database type please.  Crosstab or Pivot is what you are trying here

Comment: Basically I have the same data in MySQL too so I don't mind getting solutions for MySQL, BTW thanks @Twelfth

Comment: Go with MSSQL, you get access to commands such as 'pivot' shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714265/i-need-to-know-how-to-create-a-crosstab-query      The best you can do in MySQL is fake it...SqlZim's answer shows both.

Comment: Ok @Twelfth. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    id
  , max(case when type = 'email' then value end) as email
  , max(case when type = 'phone' then value end) as phone
  , max(case when type = 'workphone' then value end) as workphone
from t
group by id
```

or `pivot()` (in sql-server):

```
select id, email, phone, workphone
from t
pivot (max(value) for type in ([email],[phone],[workphone])) p
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UGT52844

both return:

```
+----+--------------+-------+-----------+
| id |    email     | phone | workphone |
+----+--------------+-------+-----------+
|  1 | abcd@xyz.com | 12345 | NULL      |
|  2 | NULL         | 56789 | 546789    |
+----+--------------+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to the solution above is the Pivot command in SQL Server. The following answer will only work for SQL-Server. This syntax will not work with MYSQL. You have tagged this question with both tags so I am not sure which you are running on. If you are using MSSQL the following link covers the command in depth 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot .

The following code will achieve the result you are looking for:

```
   SELECT [ID] AS [ID],
       [Email] AS Email, 
       [Phone] AS Phone,
       [WorkPhone] AS WorkPhone
   FROM 
   (
        SELECT ID, 
               [TYPE], 
               [Value] 
        FROM dbo.Pivot_Ex
   ) AS FT
   PIVOT 
   (
        MAX([Value])
        FOR FT.TYPE IN ([Email], [Phone], WorkPhone)
   ) AS PivotTable1
```